# Javascript Math functions & arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

Why are functions like Math.cos() and Math.sin() not working on array?  So if I have an array, do I have to loop through to compute the cosine of all numbers in the array?  Is there a distinction between arrays and matrices?  Can I define a 2-dimensional matrix and access the elements using subscripts like x[2,3] for 2nd row and 3rd column?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes you have to iterate yourself. The `Math` trig functions work on individual values only.
2. JavaScript really has only one-dimensional arrays, but values of a one-dimensional array can be arrays. That gives an effect like multi-dimensional arrays, but it's really not exactly the same thing. (For most programming purposes, it's close enough.)
3. Multiple dimensions are accessed as `myArray[1][2]`, not with a comma-separated list of indexes.

Comment: @canon they accept multiple arguments, but they do *not* accept **arrays** (unless they're called via `.apply()` of course). The point is that they're not "vector" operations. Still, edited to stipulate "trig functions".